# How to Merge PDF file with Annotation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, pdf, pdf-annotations

i used this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553540/merge-pdf-files-on-ios) 's code to merge pdf file ,pdf merge sucessfully with loss of annotation i want to merge pdf with annotattion i checked following link:

[How to Merge Multiple PDF Files Into One PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383010/how-to-merge-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf)

[Merge 2 pdf files in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430812/merge-2-pdf-files-in-ios)

any other method to merge pdf file with annotation

Please Help me

Comment: were you able to add annotations to PDF? How? I am struggling with the same.

Comment: thanks for replying.. Which library have you used? Can you share the link to it?

Comment: check this sample code https://github.com/xil3f/podofo_iOS_sample

Comment: thanks a lot for help.. I ll check it and let you know. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

For adding annotations to a PDF document I suggest you use this library which provides a sample code of [PSPDFKIT](http://pspdfkit.com/). Also please follow this link which has loads of methods and libraries to add annotations to a PDF file. The first one is the **PSPDFKIT** itself which is free as a demo version but includes namely all kinds of functionalities you would need generally.

[Create PDF Annotations in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888950/create-pdf-annotations-in-ios)

Answer (score -6):

If you have Adobe Acrobat Pro you can:

1. open one of the pdf you want to merge
2. open the menu Comments (top right)
3. under "Comments List" click on the option icon cf the printscreen
4. select Import data file and select the second pdf

[image]

Comment: i want merge pdf file programmatically  not desktop  using Adobe Acrobat